# Does dereferencing struct pointer copy the struct?

Tags: pointers, go

I have [this code](https://play.golang.org/p/ickKt8mPp3H):

```
type countHolder struct {
    count int
}

func main() {
    a := &countHolder{1}
    b := *a
    a.count = 2
    println(b.count)
}
```

I expected the output to be 2, but the output was 1.

My understanding was that:

1. `a := &countHolder{1}` // a is pointer to struct with data starting at address x
2. `b := *a` // b now equals address x
3. `a.count = 2` // the struct stored at address x has its count value changed to 2

Where am I wrong? is `b := *a` creating a copy of the struct?

Comment: I am no go expert, but dereferencing would make it a struct not a pointer to one so type of b would be a countHolder struct, and assignment thereof would copy the contents...

Comment: Your line 2 explanation is wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x. [...]
>
> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x. [...]

That means that the unary `&` operator gives you the address of something so `a` in:

```
a := &countHolder{1}
```

is a pointer. The unary `*` operator in:

```
b := *a
```

dereferences the pointer `a` and leaves you with a `countHolder` struct on the right side so `b` is a copy of the struct that `a` points to. Since `b` is a copy of the struct, modifying `a.count`:

```
a.count = 2
```

(which could also be written as `(*a).count = 2`) won't have any affect on `b`.

You could also have a look at (https://play.golang.org/p/Zubs8qYBA_K):

```
func main() {
    a := &countHolder{1}
    b := *a
    fmt.Printf("%T\n%T\n", a, b)
}
```

to have a quick look at what types `a` and `b` are (`*counterHolder` and `counterHolder`, respectively, in this case).